# Error multiDex when updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-multidex

when i updating my android studio to `3.1.2` i got this error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList

build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
productFlavors {
}
}
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.example.ApplicationManager">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And `com.example.ApplicationManager`

```
public class ApplicationManager extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
public class ApplicationManager extends MultiDexApplication{

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `application` class in extend:
Use below class in extends application class:

```
public class ApplicationManager extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
   super.attachBaseContext(base);
   MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

and also put this line in application class in manifest:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_new"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```